# How to make a button in android to pops up a menu?

Tags: android, button, menu

I want a menu (the one that is triggered by the Menu button on the device) to work from a click on a normal button (an on screen one, of course)..
in a way to "replace" the Menu button on the device on one that is on screen.

Any ideas?

Comment: give an example, please?

Comment: Why don't you use the ActionBar? It provides a menu button and it is recommended to be used ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easily

```
public void onClick(View v){
    openOptionsMenu(); 
}
```

Then to override the menu buttons behavior (this is not really reccomended) you can do something like this

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU ) {
        Log.d(TAG, "MENU pressed");
        return false;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Thanks!ya, that one was what i looked for... sorry for the stupid Q :)

Comment: Not a stupid Q, I'm not sure why people needed an example to know what your were talking about.  I thought it was rather obvious

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/)'s one way.  I use this in my code, and it works really great.

Edit: I think I misunderstood your intention.  If you want to programmatically launch the standard menu (as if the menu button was pressed) at some other time, call `openOptionsMenu();`.